# Where can I learn about text compression in Java?

Tags: java, compression, zip

Where can I learn about text compression in Java?

What classes would be used, and how would I use them?

Answer (score 4):

[java.util.zip](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html)?

Answer (score 2):

The `java.util.zip` package contains `GZIPInputStream` and `GZipOutputStream`, you can easily combine those with other `java.io` streams to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

[Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) provides some useful encoding/decoding classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Google results are very informative: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example coding showing how to use Deflate, Filtered, bzip2, and lzma compression in Java. h[ttp://www.theeggeadventure.com/wikimedia/index.php/Java_Data_Compression](http://www.theeggeadventure.com/wikimedia/index.php/Java_Data_Compression)

For most of the stream based classes, you add them inline with your existing Java IO methods.  If you are reading or writing to a file, and can compress/uncompress by adding a filter to your stream.  The same can be said for sockets and other IO.